# If <video> is specified with a remote url, and the user plays the file, does the file get streamed or downloaded?

Tags: uiwebview

If I launch a web page using UIWebView and that page contains a  tag with a url specifying a remote video file, then when the user clicks the video to watch it what happens?

Does the web engine stream the video, or download it somewhere, if it downloads it then as its playing within my app is it placed in my app's sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView is just creating a Safari browser component, so it should have the same behaviour as it.

The  tag in HTML5 for Safari has suport for MP4 format for video, and AAC or MP3 for audio. It will be streamed by means of [HTTP Live Streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/hls/) and (only in iOS) [Adaptive Streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/#adaptive_streaming). I belive that will be done within Safari's sandbox.